# Correct syntax for update query with inner join

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, android-room

I'm trying to update the field `buyPrice` in all the products that match a query, what is the correct syntax for this?

I'm getting this error

```
An error occurred while running the statement: sub-select returns 22 columns - expected 1 
(code 1 SQLITE_ERROR): , while compiling: UPDATE product set buyPrice = ? in 
(SELECT * FROM product p JOIN roomuser u ON p.businessId = u.currentBusinessId WHERE sellPrice 10
```

This is my query so far:

```
@Query("""
    UPDATE product 
        set buyPrice = :newPrice in 
        (SELECT * FROM 
        product p JOIN user u ON p.businessId = u.currentBusinessId
        WHERE sellPrice < 10)
    """)

suspend fun updateProduct(newPrice: Float)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want to use a WHERE clause in your UPDATE statement, which may be something like this:

```
UPDATE product 
SET buyPrice = :newPrice 
WHERE product_id IN (
  SELECT p.product_id 
  FROM product p JOIN user u 
  ON p.businessId = u.currentBusinessId
  WHERE sellPrice < 10
)
```

I use `product_id` in my code which I assume is the primary key of the table `product`.

Or, if `sellPrice` is a column of the table `product`, you could use `EXISTS` instead of the join like this:

```
UPDATE product 
SET buyPrice = :newPrice 
WHERE sellPrice < 10
  AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM user u WHERE u.currentBusinessId = product.businessId)
```